# RPA Alternate Wait Command options

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I am building a bot that is sorting large amounts of data in excel (90k lines +).  My issue is that the completion time of this command is variable ranging anywhere from a few seconds to 15 minutes.  However there are no commands that will let me proceed to the next step.  I am forced to use a delay command for 10-15 minutes.  The Wait for window or screen change command do no work because the data changes every month.  Can anyone think of an alternative solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the logic that you have?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VBscript file(.vbs) for performing your sort.

Since VBS scripts can easily get running instances of Excel and interact with them. Also VBS scripts are synchronous so AA will wait for the script to finish execution if invoked through "Run Script" command.